# Find the maximum for $P(X=Y)$ over all $X,Y$ random variable with Bernoulli distribution and with respectively the parameters $p,q$.

Tags: probability, random-variables

Find the maximum for $P(X=Y)$ over all $X,Y$ random variable with Bernoulli distribution and with respectively the parameters $p,q$.

They can be not independant.

I don't know how to find the maximum.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You could start by finding $P(X=Y)$ in terms of $p$ and $q$ and some measure of their dependence.

Comment: Okay so if I do that I have : $P(X=Y) = P(X=0)P(Y=0|X=0) + P(X=1)P(Y=1|X=1) = (1-p)×P(Y=0|X=0) + p×P(Y=1|X=1)  $

Comment: If they are perfectly correlated, the probability they are equal is $1$.

Comment: You could think about $P(X=1,Y=1)=\alpha$, $P(X=1,Y=0)=p-\alpha$,  $P(X=0,Y=1)=q-\alpha$, $P(X=0,Y=0)=1-p-q+\alpha$ and the constraints on $\alpha$.

Comment: @ZoeAllen Your idea will not work when $p \not= q$

Comment: @Henry Okay i will try with this constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $P(X=i,Y=j)=A_{ij}$ You want $$\begin{align}L(p,q)=&\max&  A_{00}+A_{11}\\ &\text{subject to}& A_{10}+A_{11}=p\\ &&A_{01}+A_{11}=q\\  &&A_{01}+A_{11}+A_{00}+A_{10}=1 \\ &&\forall i,j,\ A_{ij}\ge 0\end{align}$$

We have $A_{10}=p-A_{11}$, $A_{01}=q-A_{11}$ and $A_{00}=1-p-q+A_{11}$, with constraints $\max\{0, p+q-1\}\le A_{11}\le \min\{p,q\}$. We want to maximize $A_{00}+A_{11}=2A_{11}+1-p-q$. So the value is $$L(p,q)=2\min\{p,q\}+1-p-q=1-\lvert p-q\rvert$$

It's from the distribution that corresponds to the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1-\max\{p,q\}& q-\min\{p,q\}\\ p-\min\{p,q\}&\min\{p,q\}\end{pmatrix}=\\=\begin{pmatrix}1-\max\{p,q\}& (q-p)^+\\ (p-q)^+&\min\{p,q\}\end{pmatrix}$$